# Calculate 50% from duration in seconds?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax

Those customers on an individual customer level who spend at least 50% of their time under "Enquiry"
[image]

Like this, I will have different customer ids, different durations in `durationInSeconds` and different stages in Sub Journey Stage.
 I need a query to find out the customers who have spent there at least 50% means >=50% of their time `durationInSeconds` in Sub Journey Stage='Enquiry'.

I tried this but it is not working "sum(case when Sub_Journey_Stage='Enquiry' then durationInSeconds else 0 end) / sum(durationInSeconds)".

Comment: Images of data aren't well received here. Please take the time to provide your data as tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select sourceCustomerId
from t
group by sourceCustomerId
having sum(case when sub_journy_stage = 'Enquiry' then duration end) > 0.5 * sum(duration);
```